# The profile page is scrambled when using a wide image

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

All is said in the title, the profile page look horrible both on the main and meta site. I think this is due to the fact that I am using a wide image.

> [image]

---

If I remove the image it's fine:

> [image]

And with the image it is supposed to look like this:

> [image]

Comment: while the issue is clearly visible in your profile (to me at least), you might want to post a screenshot in the question, in case the issue doesn't show up on other people's browsers, they cannot replicate it for other reasons, or even just for reference after the issue is fixed.

Comment: @DavisBroda edited

Comment: What'd you put in your profile

Comment: @Makoto a simple image ...

Comment: Btw... The challenge in that image isn't a real challenge for anyone who can read it normally. ;) The slant does make it slightly harder than reading it upside down, but I can totally still read that.

Comment: @Kendra well, I will try  to make it harder then :p

Comment: I think a horizontal scrollbar in the bio would be the best option here.

Comment: @Adam I think they should keep it as it was before, even the scroll won't be good ... I liked how the overflow was hidden and I made the image big enough to have it partially cut.

Comment: Here's another profile page where the formatting gets a little messed up: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/315588/insanecat . Might be a similar issue with images.

Comment: I have a big monitor so I don't see the error (just fyi, as it might be due to that). Also, what's the challenge? Anyone who knows how to save an image and rotate then flip it can read it (as a bonus, non-css: create an NLP program that recognizes letters, upside down and with slant, and interprets - time it took 8 min) ;)

Comment: Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea Though in this case not the right side of the profile got a hit but the left one!

Comment: Same happens on my profile.

Comment: Also brought up in [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316111/stack-exchange-usercard-squeezer-on-profile-page)

Comment: What exactly is "horrible" about that? The fact that the design doesn't anticipate someone putting an image that is too large for the space provided? Sounds like that's a problem... for the person who put the image in there. :P

Comment: @HereticMonkey The system should crop or resize the image automatically. being able to break something just by providing the proper input is not good, it means the system isn't robust enough.

Comment: @Polygnome There is a long distance (in my mind) from "the system isn't robust enough" to "horrible". The OP has since edited that bit of hyperbole out of the question, which makes it a more reasonable bug (again, in my mind).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I never said anything about it being horrible. I am just pointing out that it is good engineering practice to cope with all valid inputs and not to break on some of them. Even if it is so trivial things like the layout.Because it really isn't the problem of the person providing the image - the fault is the software not handling it correctly/gracefully.

Comment: It's slightly disappointing that Stack Exchange's frontend devs are making this sort of mistake. And it's another case of "fixing" something that wasn't broken. I could be wrong, but it looks like this happened because the profile page was refactored to use [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/base/grid).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374804/walls-of-text-distort-user-profiles?noredirect=1#comment634674_374804 The image is not the issue.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: See my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled-when-using-a-wide-image#comment636042_374812) :)

Comment: If this is not fixed yet, I recommend either commenting on the answer or asking another question.

Comment: @Braiam I already did :https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-t And I commented but still nothing ..

Comment: @thirtydot in case intrested, they have finally fixed the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Nice to know, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

We have indeed been doing some refactoring. Thanks for pointing this out. It *should* be fixed, and will go live in the next build.

Comment: This is still slightly broken in some cases. Naturally discovered example: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/180/karl-bielefeldt / https://i.stack.imgur.com/CakFc.png. I'm sure there are worse ones out there, to demonstrate I've [broken my profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uaow.png) for science: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/22721/thirtydot?tab=profile. I'm using a recent version of Chrome. This new layout is less robust than the old one. Good luck!

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/57/jollymort

Comment: @thirtydot here is the fix `.fl1{min-width:0}` ;) .. should be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size :p

Comment: there is a use of class `wmx25` that need to be changed to `wmn25` I guess