# Another bug in the profile page (questions/answers_list)___[I_will_make_this_title_long_enough_to_be_able_to_reproduce_the_issue_on_meta]

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, design

Here is another bug <sup>**2**</sup>

[image: Screenshot of Newest Questions list on the main site.]

Also on meta with this question:

[image: Screenshot of Newest Questions on Meta.]

As we can see, when the title of the question is very long, the accepted icon is truncated and the *time text* is taking 2 lines.

This is a common flexbox issue as by default all the elements will shrink [when the total size exceed the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492208/why-is-a-flex-child-limited-to-parent-size/49492522#49492522). We need to consider adding `flex-shrink:0` to `.icon-a` and probably add `white-space:nowrap` to the time text to avoid line break *(I tested it and it's working)*.

---

**<sup>2</sup> The bug is now different (update 31/05/2019)**.

Below is a screenshot of the profile page. In the Top Questions list, the very long question title pushes the date to the right.

[image]

Comment: 99 little bugs in the code, 99 little bugs, take one down, patch it around, 127 little bugs in the code!

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. Working on a fix that should be going out with the next build in a few hours.

Comment: Should probably also test a long, unbroken string as well, such as "AHHHHHHHHHHHHH [...] HHHHH" (where the [...] is 700 omitted H's).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn you are right, I added this case too which is also breaking the layout ;)

Comment: @JonH.M.Chan please consider the update made to the question ... I noticed you fixed one issue by the way

Comment: Be VERY careful with break-word. Youll end up effecting a lot more than you expect.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn *they* need to be very careful :) more than they are actually by the way

Comment: It's nice to have a user-moderated site where the overall goal trends towards quality though, lets you skip some corners. If you get a user posting "AHHHHHHHHHHHHH [...] HHHHH" he will be viciously removed by plenty of users, likely before a mod even sees it.

Comment: At least the main issue here looks fixed when I take a look at your profile

Comment: @Luuklag not yet for me ...

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn **[C̨̦̺̩̲̥͉̭͚̜̻̝̣̼͙̮̯̪o̴̡͇̘͎̞̲͇̦̲͞͡m̸̩̺̝̣̹̱͚̬̥̫̳̼̞̘̯͘ͅẹ͇̺̜́̕͢ - What kind of string is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184958/c%CC%A8%CC%A6%CC%BA%CC%A9%CC%B2%CC%A5%CD%89%CC%AD%CD%9A%CC%9C%CC%BB%CC%9D%CC%A3%CC%BC%CD%99%CC%AE%CC%AF%CC%AAo%CC%B4%CC%A1%CD%87%CC%98%CD%8E%CC%9E%CC%B2%CD%87%CC%A6%CC%B2%CD%9E%CD%A1m%CC%B8%CC%A9%CC%BA%CC%9D%CC%A3%CC%B9%CC%B1%CD%9A%CC%AC%CC%A5%CC%AB%CC%B3%CC%BC%CC%9E%CC%98%CC%AF%CD%98%CD%85%E1%BA%B9%CD%87%CC%BA%CC%9C%CC%81%CC%95%CD%A2-what-kind-of-string)**

Comment: @JonH.M.Chan why is it taking too long to fix this bug?

Comment: @JonChan how's that fix coming dude?

Comment: @SamSwift웃 [Reminds me of this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165623/99-bugs-in-the-code).

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd recommend asking a separate question; you'll get better luck than with editing this one.

Comment: @TylerH there is already 3 other questions about : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382712/8620333 / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380861/8620333 / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385634/8620333 ...

Answer (score 7):

This should be fixed now!  We've applied that min-width: 0 fix.

Comment: finally! please make this one completed too : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled-when-using-a-wide-image-not-fixed .. since it's the same bug

Comment: nevermind, it was already set as completed ..

Comment: It's back! I see the same broken behaviour if I go to [Temani's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).

Answer (score -4):

To be able to post the printscreen I'll write this as an answer.

To me the main problem (long question titles disturbing the layout) is fixed, perhaps caching is preventing you from properly seeing your own profile?

[image: Screenshot from profile of Temani Afif]

Comment: Try visiting [Temani Afif's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif), do you see text running into the margin there?

Comment: That wasn't the primary issue of this post, and that part isn't fixed yet.

Comment: oh you mean this one, Yes it was fixed and I already commented it ;) and for me the other one was the main issue since I already added a previous question so I repeat it here again since it's wasn't fixed correctly

Comment: Well @TemaniAfif your title says the issue that is solved is your main issue. It is better to have each issue in a seperate Q.

Comment: @Luuklag this is what I have done : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled-when-using-a-wide-image-not-fixed and they made it `status-completed` so I insisted again here that is not yet fixed ... and both issues are related because they made changes to the whole profile page and a lot of glitchs appeared ... I don't think it's productive to have a question for each small bug, they should consider the whole thing and repare it