# Please break titles on words, not letters

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, title

For readability, when a title spans on multiple lines, please split it on words, not on letters.

Otherwise we get this undesirable behavior:

[image]

(illustration taken from [Web Storm identifier expected error when I use brace to pass vue function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424345/web-storm-identifier-expected-error-when-i-use-brace-to-pass-vue-function-parame))

To solve it, you may **remove** this from Stack Overflow CSS:

```
word-break: break-all !important;
```

[image]

Comment: Remove it? But... it's *!important*.

Comment: I never really understood "!important". I always read it as "not important".

Comment: break-word !important should work fine.

Comment: Reported on Meta.SE: [On sites with new responsive theme, word wrap on long titles breaks in the middle of a word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318655/289905).

Comment: Butthenwhatifatitleistypedlikethisandtheheaderextendsoverthespacethatitcanhaveforthequestion?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne, if you see that: downvote, close as "unclear", and delete with prejudice...  ... Er, I mean edit it or something.

Comment: They should not remove the `word-break: break-all !important;` from that CSS entry (that entry will be re-used anywhere SE wants a `break-all`). SE has gone retro and moved to using classes to assign individual CSS properties, basically using CSS classes as if they were `style` entries on each element. So, the thing that would need to be removed is the `wb-break-all` class from the `<h1 itemprop="name" class="grid--cell fs-headline1 fl1 wb-break-all">` element.

Comment: for sure related to this bug I made : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit ...  they fix the title issue and now created another one

Comment: @codemirror it's not supported on Firefix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Makyen You're probably correct about removing this specific class from the name/headline. But I would be surprised to find legitimate cases for a `word-break: break-all` instead of using `overflow-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: @Cœur some non-latin languages readers actually prefer to see their words cut in the middle rather than having weird spaces between words or at the end of the line. I personally don't like it, but I discovered it is the standard for instance here were I emigrated... (Though for titles it's still just very weird IMO)

Comment: +1. In my [What is the correct term for the list that initializes the data members in a constructor definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444145/what-is-the-correct-term-for-the-list-that-initializes-the-data-members-in-a-con), the title is broken in "con" and "structor", while it would made it much more elegant to be broken before "constructor".

Comment: Maybe Enable hyphenation?

Comment: @dualed I wouldn't be surprised if hyphenation will not be implemented. Loading a hyphenation dictionary each page load sounds like a lot, as well as programming terms (function/variable names especially) not being included in that. Breaking on spaces sounds a lot easier.

Comment: For most SE sites no dictionary should be needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I'm almost certain this didn't used to be the case; I've never noticed it before and I'm *sure* it would've been complained about before now. Any idea when this changed?

Comment: I agree with Mark - I hadn't noticed this even once until I ran across this Q earlier today; since then I've witnessed the problem a handful of times across SO.

Comment: Just curious—do the down-voters prefer line-wrapping to break up words?

Comment: @MarkAmery it wasn't the case. it was probably changed due to this bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: There's been a regression: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49295835/6296561

Answer (score 29):

The proper solution to this, noted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18628052/1709587, is not to simply remove `word-break: break-all` but rather to replace it with `overflow-wrap: break-word`, whose behaviour, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) is:

> To prevent overflow, normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

This will cause browsers to wrap at word breaks where possible, but will prevent titlesdeliberatelycraftedtocontainsingleverylongwordswithnospaceslikethisobnoxiousfuckerimcreatingherethatiswiderthanthepost from breaking the site's layout. Indeed, I'd think that `word-break: break-all` probably shouldn't be used *anywhere* in Stack Exchange's codebase, and would suggest that they audit the codebase for any occurrence of it and replace each of them with `overflow-wrap: break-word` unless there's some really good reason not to.

They still get this *right* within post bodies, as I've demonstrated above, so I'm not sure how they managed to break it in titles.

Comment: If you could put that long title in CamelCase, that would make it a bit easier to parse.

Comment: Tried testing `break-word` in the formatting sandbox on meta, but it didn't work. Ended up [looking up the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break). Firefox doesn't support it. That is `word-break: break-word`. The one you linked is for `overflow-wrap: break-word;`.

Comment: @Zoe Darn it, you're right. I got confused by the `overflow-wrap` vs `word-wrap` vs `word-break` distinction. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I couldn't get `overflow-wrap: break-word` to break anything. Might be some horrible setup on my end though

Comment: @Zoe Hmm... it definitely works for me. Try inspecting the post div, in Firefox or Chrome, and toggling off the `word-wrap: break-word` there (note that `word-wrap` and `overflow-wrap` are synonyms) and you'll see the long word in my post suddenly reach out to overlap with the Hot Network Questions.

Comment: Probably a local problem then ^^" The JSFiddle in the SO question you linked works, so it's a setup problem. `word-wrap`/`overflow-wrap` should work.