# Line near side of profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I was looking at a user's profile, and found there was a line straight through the text.

[image]

The line continued through the entire page, top to bottom. I suspect this is intended to be the right border of the profile page, that ended shifted over a bit.

[profile where this occurs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1481116/luuklag)

Occurs using Firefox 66.0.2

Does not occur when I access the same page with Google Chrome 73.0.3683.103

Comment: Probably due to the 3rd answer from below.

Comment: makes sense. a really long question name pushing the data past the border seems like the most probable cause.

Comment: No problem adding the link, only found out it is my profile after clicking it. Didn't even notice it in the screenshot :O

Comment: @DavisBroda I mean it's kind of hard to hide anyway, I found it by searching one of the question titles

Comment: the never ending bug related to this question : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375101/8620333

Comment: Subsequent user profile redesigns seems to have fixed this.