# (non-Stack) Overflow of top tags and posts on Meta

Tags: bug, profile-page

I just saw [Temani Afif](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)'s profile, and something weird has happened to the top tags and answers:

[image: Profile in question]
<sub>Sorry for the freehand "circles"</sub>

However, this doesn't happen to everyone - here's my profile:

[image: My profile]

I believe this is due to the extremely long [Another bug in the profile page (questions/answers_list)___[I_will_make_this_title_long_enough_to_be_able_to_reproduce_the_issue_on_meta]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit). Can this bug be fixed please?

<sub>(I know it's kind of a continuation of the question, but I didn't think it also affected the tags)</sub>

Reproduction list (edit and comment):

- Safari
- Chrome

Comment: I can reproduce on chrome as well. To those who can't; make sure you're sorting the top posts by 'votes' rather than 'newest'

Comment: It's not "votes" vs. "newest" that affects it, it's "questions" vs. "answers". You have to get [that question with the ridiculously long title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit) to show up. It is another "doctor, it hurts when I do this" problem.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380861/8620333 / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382712/8620333 .. this bug will never get fixed I guess

Comment: Since his profile is about challenges in css, I actually thought that maybe he did that on purpose somehow.

Comment: Edge and Firefox show the same issue. It might also be an intentional and intricate joke, though.