# Comments in the responses tab on Meta have overflowing rows

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, meta

Location is "Responses" tab in the "Activity" view: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses

This only affects the Meta profile page; the main SO profile page doesn't have this issue. This is a screen shot from my profile https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh?tab=responses

[image: overflowing table row items]

Comment: Probably specific to that comment by Temani, since it specifically doesn't wrap (and was meant not to). For instance, my list does not show this problem

Comment: oh my god, again that bug ... it will haunt SO for life.

Comment: Related, probably duplicate: [(non-Stack) Overflow of top tags and posts on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385634/4642212).

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd call it a "feature" and be done with it. It's part of the **Stack** Exchange network that **overflows**. It's branding and marketing strategy. SE should file a trademark for it. Maybe even patent the technology to protect themselves from other sites trying to copy their success by copying the overflowing UI. (just to be clear, this is a joke)

Comment: Step 1: Ban @Temani Afif. Step 2: Delete all his posts. Step 3: There is no step 3; bug has been resolved.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow? What?