# Profile page display bug on users "keeping a low profile"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

[This profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1424290/s%C3%A9bastien-gicquel) doesn't display properly

[image]

The right part is way too small and the lines underneath the description aren't aligned.

Comment: OS and browser version?

Comment: related : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled-when-using-a-wide-image-not-fixed?noredirect=1&lq=1 ...https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-t?noredirect=1&lq=1 ... this seems related to the same thing

Comment: @SamuelLiew Windows 10 & latest Chrome (69)

Comment: there is a class `wmx25` need to be changed to `wmn25`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good inspecting.

Comment: It's all over the network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316305/some-profile-pages-are-messed-up-in-sites-with-the-new-responsive-design.

Comment: Did you pick this random user because it's the only profile that displays badly? Your own, for example, is okay?

Comment: @usr2564301 It wasn't the only one, but it was one I stumbled upon ^^

Comment: @Shog9 is this bug https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit and this one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled-when-using-a-wide-image-not-fixed still considered? I commented/edited a lot of times and got no replies.