# Another profile bug related to website link field

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The website link field fails when we try to use some characters at the start of the link and this will create an issue in the profile page when the link is very long:

> [image]

*I have used `!` at the start of my link*

It seems that the system is failing to correctly create the link and we end with a text inside a div instead of an `a` tag:

> [image]

We should probably add more tests in order to avoid such issue. There is already some tests that detect bad links and show you errors like below but it seems not enough:

> [image]

<sup>I want also to remind about another old bug not fixed ([The profile page is scrambled when using a wide image [not fixed]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled-when-using-a-wide-image-not-fixed))</sup>

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319237/heading-bug-on-profiles-on-area-51

Comment: @Zoe I don't think for this bug but probably for the old one in the bottom of the question

Comment: @TemaniAfif how did you make up 10K reputation in 3 months?!

Comment: @WaisKamal in just **2 months** not in 3 months